# MVC3 jquery ajax parameter data is null at controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a controller action that I want to update via a jquery call.  The action runs, but there is no data in the parameters.

I am using a kedoui grid with a custom command in a column that I want to run some server code.

```
kendoui grid in view
...
columns.Command(command =>
{
    command.Custom("ToggleRole").Click("toggleRole");
});
...
```

The model is of type List<_AdministrationUsers>.

```
public class _AdministrationUsers
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid UserID { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my toggleRole Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function toggleRole(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
         alert(JSON.stringify(dataItem));

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("ToggleRole", "Administration")',
             data: JSON.stringify(dataItem),
             success: function () {
                 RefreshGrid();
             },
             error: function () {
                 RefreshGrid()
             }
         });
     }
</script>
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ToggleRole(string UserID, string UserName, string Role)
{
    ...
}
```

**The controller action fires, but there is no data in any of the parameters.**

I put the alert in the javascript to verify that there is indeed data in the "dataItem" variable.  Here is what the alert text looks like:

```
{"UserID":"f9f1d175...(etc.)","UserName":"User1","Role","Admin"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try specifying the dataType and contentType  in you ajax post ?

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("ToggleRole", "Administration")',
             data: JSON.stringify(dataItem),
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function () {
                 RefreshGrid();
             },
             error: function () {
                 RefreshGrid()
             }
         });
```

Comment: point of interest here: dataType is for the expected return type where as contentType is the data being sent to the server. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for this. This answer helped me too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are posting the whole object as one Json string, while the controller expects three strings. If you are using MVC3 the parameter names also have to match the controllers signature. Try to parse up your data object so that it matches the input expected from the controller. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: '@Url.Action("ToggleRole", "Administration")',
             data: { UserID: dataItem.UserID, UserName: dataItem.UserID, Role: dataItem.Role },
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function () {
                 RefreshGrid();
             },
             error: function () {
                 RefreshGrid()
             }
         });
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  GX noticed that I didn't have dataType or contentType specified.  Once I did that, it all worked as expected.  I didn't need to parse the data.  I was even able to get rid of (string, string, string) and just use my view model for the controller parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
{"UserID":"f9f1d175...(etc.)","UserName":"User1","Role","Admin"}
```

Seems incorrect to me. Wouldn't you want this?

```
{"UserID":"f9f1d175...(etc.)","UserName":"User1","Role" : "Admin"}
```

Notice the "Role" : "Admin"

Comment: Sorry, I just mis-typed it.  I wasn't able to copy/paste the alert message.  Good catch, though.